# How can I get .NET/Silverlight source code symbols to work in VS 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols

Back when M$ first released the ability to point visual studio at a symbol server and actually debug into .NET code I got it up and working no problem on VS2008.

Now trying to do this with VS2010 or my local copy of VS2008 doesn't seem to work.  It successfully downloads the symbols and the stack frames turn from gray to black but there is no source available.

Has anyone gotten this working?  If so what's the secret?  Also is there source available for Silverlight included?

Answer (score 2):

VS2010 does not have the .NET 4 source released to the source servers yet. See [this note](http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com/documentation) from a downloader tool, which states pdbs are there but sources are not yet.

**EDIT:** Some people have reported getting it working after manually downloading the source from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).